# Detect the use of a pop up blocker

Tags: javascript

> ***Problem solved***

First of all, I apologise for my poor English.

I would like to detect whether the client's browser blocked a pop up frame or not.
I have searched many sites and integrated many answers into one. My implementation is as  follows:

```
var newWin =       
    window.open("abc.html", "", 
    "directories = no, height = 1000, width = 1000, menubar = no, resizable = no, 
     scrollbars = no, status = no, titlebar = no, top = 0, location = no");
// alert true if the blocker is enabled
setTimeout( function() 
{
    if (!newWin || newWin.closed ||
        typeof newWin.closed == 'undefined' || newWin.outerHeight === 0)
        alert("true");
    else
    {
        alert("false");
    }, 25);
```

However, not all browsers give the expected response.

Only Firefox 22, Safari 5.1.7, Opera 12 give the expected response.

Chrome 27 and IE 10 did not give the expected response.

Are there any other way to detect the Pop up blocker? Thank you.

Comment: Chrome 27 seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wMzYd/

Comment: It's work to me too...but it's does not work on my site =V=
finding the bug..

Comment: Don't use pop ups, it's as simple as that. Pop up blockers exist for that exact reason, nobody wants popups.

Comment: @Zachrip Pop ups are sometimes required. For example, when a user is in a page you do not want to force navigate away from, but wish to warn them of a pending time out. Also easier to use for some form submissions to remove browser navigation. This is normally in effort to prevent them from using a back button(s). We as programmers, know that even if we tell users "Don't use XYZ buttons", they will inevitably do it anyways. :(

Comment: I am using the exact same logic, and it works for all boxes across all browsers except for one box using IE 11. Not sure why.